# Does git garbage collection interrupt pull requests?

Tags: git, jgit

If a repository has a high probability of a pull request happening at any given time, will issuing a garbage collection interrupt a pull attempt in any way?

Comment: you mean when you are doing multiple things on a Git repository in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

I think it probably be okay.

Robin Rosenberg, a commiter of jgit, answered my question "is jgit gc is safe while pushing?" as below.

> I think the *intention* is that it should be safe, but I don't know if
>   that holds up in the big world. Time will tel....

http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jgit-dev/msg02293.html